# How to do push-force in gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I did changes in my branch, for example: `Task1` and i did push with the following command: `git-review`. but now, after that it's uploaded to gerrit server, I dropped some commits and I created new commits (on same branch) and I want to push it to gerrit server.

How can I do that? How can I do it with `git-review` command?  (I want to overwrite the previous branch I uploaded)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the change-id at the bottom of your commit message is the same, Gerrit will recognise them as being the same change. If you have multiple commits in a new branch, push the new branch and Gerrit should work out what's going on. If you navigate to one of the dropped commits in Gerrit it should list the others as 'Indirect Ancestor' or 'Not current' but if you've dropped them locally, you can probably abandon them in Gerrit through the UI.

Comment: I didn't understand, I work on the same branch. And in my local repo I deleted the existing commits, and created new commits. And now I want to update it in Gerrit. And overwrite what currently appears under this branch in Gerrit.

Comment: Have you already merged the change in gerrit?

Comment: no i just did git-review

Comment: if you make the changes you want to make locally and run `git-review` again, gerrit should work out what is going on. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, but i still see the old commits in the dashbord. it's ok ?

Comment: Yes. You can abandon the changes that are no longer required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247306/discussion-between-jobprocesstask-and-holloway).